# Conjugated vs. isomorphic subgroups from the standpoint of their Cayley's embedding into the symmetric group of their parent group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of the group $G$. Being $H$ and $K$ conjugated is a stronger condition than being them just isomorphic. Accordingly, I expect that there is some distinctive feature between Cayley's embeddings of $H$ and $K$ into $S_G$, in the two cases. (By Cayley's embedding of a subgroup $H$ into the symmetric group of the parent group $G$, I mean the composition of some embedding of $S_H$ into $S_G$, after the truly Cayley's embedding of $H$ into $S_H$.) Is it so?

Comment: Not really? If $H, K \leq G$ are isomorphic then they are conjugate in $\mathrm{Sym}(G)$. If they were conjugate already then they are conjugate in the subgroup $G \leq \mathrm{Sym}(G)$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, does it mean the in the first case ($H,K$ isomorphic, nonconjugate), $H$'s and $K$'s isomorphic (Cayley) images in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ are conjugate by a permutation which does necessarily *not* lie in the isomorphic (Cayley) image of $G$?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me prove Sean Eberhard's claim in the comments: Let $\sigma_H:H\to S_H$ and $\sigma_K:K\to S_K$ be the Cayley embeddings, i.e. $\sigma_H(h)(x)=hx$ for $h,x\in H$. Let $\gamma:H\to K$ be an isomorphim. Then $\gamma$ can be extended to an element $\hat\gamma\in S_G$.
Let $h\in H$ and $x\in K$. Then
$$\hat\gamma\sigma_H(h)\hat\gamma^{-1}(x)=\hat\gamma(h\gamma^{-1}(x))=\gamma(h)x=\sigma_K(\gamma(h))(x).$$ This shows that $\sigma_H(H)$ and $\sigma_K(K)$ are conjugate in $S_G$ via $\hat\gamma$.

Comment: And does $\hat\gamma\in\sigma_G(G)$ if and only if $K=gHg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$? I think this was my main point then.

Comment: Not quite, since $\hat\gamma$ is not uniquely determined. But if $H$ and $K$ are conjugate in $G$, then $\hat\gamma$ can be chosen to lie in $S_G$.

Comment: But for $\hat\gamma$ chosen to lay in $S_G$, $H$ and $K$ isomorphic suffices (you have shown that in the answer). I wonder whether the stronger condition $H$ and $K$ conjugate ends up with the conjugating element to lay in the Cayley image $\sigma_G(G)$, rather than generally in $S_G$.